# Thin translucency node in cycle

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, shaders

I thought it was pretty straight forward  to do this just by mixing shader until I saw this https://devtalk.blender.org/t/diffuse-translucency-way-too-difficult-to-set-up-in-cycles/807   .So I group these nodes and achieve good result.However,I still need other nodes in Principle BSDF such as specular ,normal to achieve other results.I wonder if I can add these nodes to my node group without causing other problems.[image]

Comment: The shader is used to shade object that should have thin thickness but not due to modeling convenience such as leaf.